# New tag for Buy/Purchase/Shop?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have enough questions asking about how to buy various products, I wonder if a tag would be helpful in categorizing and finding them.

As someone who uses tag searches, it would be helpful to me. Say I'm looking for advice on the process of buying a guitar, I could quickly search "[shopping](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shopping)[guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guitar)" to see what questions have already been asked and advice given.

The tag wiki would, of course, be explicit that buying *process* questions are on topic, but requests for *recommendations*, *reviews*, and *stores* are not.

Comment: [Shopping help is explicitly off-topic in our FAQ](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). If those questions are off-topic, what exactly is the tag going to be used for? What grouping does shopping give us over a keyword search on a desired tag?

Comment: @Dom My understanding is that shopping *process* questions, like "what should I look for in a new X" or "How important is feature Y" are on topic. Certainly we've answered many questions along those lines. The benefit of a dedicated tag would be that some posts don't explicitly use words like "buy" or "purchase". For example, [How do you identify a good acoustic guitar?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1496/70803) would be missed in a keyword search limited to questions.

Comment: But why would we group them together? What does being a tag expert in shopping mean? For example, we don't group major chords together as a tag since the group doesn't mean much by itself. Shopping for an acoustic guitar and keyboard have little overlap, so what does the tag in common there mean. Another option may be make sure the equipment tag is on all these questions since you are looking beyond the instrument itself and equipment helps encapsulate that.

Comment: @Dom That makes good sense. It doesn't work as tag unto itself, and the "equipment" tag seems to cover the territory in a logical way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tags should stand on their own as a category. A [shopping](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shopping) tag doesn't meet this standard. One is not an expert in "shopping" per se, and the tag only makes sense here when paired with another: [shopping](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shopping)[guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guitar), for example.

Using the [equipment](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equipment) tag encapsulates the idea of shopping sufficiently.